# I am using sass min function on width - min(100% - 40px , 1000px); but the mapped css file shows invalid property value for min function

Tags: css, sass

Sass file: _grid.scss

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    gap: 40px;
    width: min(100% - 40px, 1000px);
    margin-inline: auto;
    @media (min-width: 900px) {
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
    }
```

Compiled CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 40px;
  width: min(100% - 40px, 1000px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
</div>
```

It shows invalid property value for `width` in cssTree although it works in the browser.

I used `calc()` function to first calculate -- `(100% - 40px)`, then I created a SASS function to return the `calc` value of the same expression but still it show the same problem.

Comment: [CSS min() already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) perhaps your version of sass doesn't know that.

Comment: This is probably a bug with cssTree. I would suggest logging a bug with the cssTree github.

Comment: `width: min(100% - 40px, 1000px);` is correct use of the css min function. Your validation tool is [csstree](https://github.com/csstree/csstree)? There is an [open issue](https://github.com/csstree/csstree/issues/164) that `min`, `max`, `clamp` are not yet supported.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to answer. Can anyone suggest an alternative css validation tool?